Git server on a webhost (non-root) account
I need to make a pull-only git server on an account provided by the web hosting company. I don't have root access on this account, but I can login and put whatever I want in an .htaccess file.
I'm trying to use git-http-backend (available on the server) to host a git server. The trouble is that all the instructions I have found use the ScriptAlias directive, which is not available in a .htaccess file.
My workaround is to use PHP to exec git-http-backend. I'm looking for some examples on how to do that.

You don't need Apache to run a cgi program. Replace it with something simpler.
The busybox http server can run cgi scripts. If we structure a $HOME/web directory like this:
web
├── cgi-bin
│   ├── git
└── repos
    ├── openvi.git
    └── surf.git

Where web/cgi-bin/git looks like this:
#!/bin/sh

GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL=1
GIT_PROJECT_ROOT=$HOME/web/repos
export GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL GIT_PROJECT_ROOT

exec git http-backend

Then we can run the busybox http server like this:
cd $HOME/web
busybox httpd -p 8080 -f

And from somewhere else we can run:
$ git clone http://myserver:8080/cgi-bin/git/openvi.git
Cloning into 'openvi'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 4881, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (4881/4881), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (1239/1239), done.
remote: Total 4881 (delta 3575), reused 4881 (delta 3575), pack-reused 0 (from 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (4881/4881), 3.15 MiB | 58.69 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (3575/3575), done.

Nothing here requires root access.
